# Insight into coupled pair of complex equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I have two complex functions $Z_1 = \frac{1}{\alpha_1 -i(Z_2 - \alpha_2)}$ and $Z_2=\frac{i Z_1^2}{ \beta_1 + i\beta_2}$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$ all lie between $0$ and $1$. How can one plot the amplitudes $|Z_1|$ and $|Z_2|$?

Comment: If $Z_2$ is in terms of $Z_1$, why not subsubstitute that expression into the first expression  then solve for $Z_1$ using the first expression via `NSolve`.  Once have $Z_1$ then can solve for $Z_2$ using the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

We first define 2 equations, solve for z2 and replace z2 in z1 by the solutions:

```
eq = {z1 == 1/(a1 - I (z2 - a2)),
   z2 == I z1^2/(b1 + I b2)};
fun1 = z1 /. Solve[eq, z1, z2];
```

Now we have 4 arguments and we would need a 5 dimensional space to plot this. But we can define a "Manipulate" where we plot the first 2 arguments and look at the second 2 arguments as parameters:

```
funs1[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] = Abs /@ fun1;
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate@funs1[a1, a2, b1, b2], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}]
 , {b1, 0.001, 1}, {b2, .001, 1}]
```

[image]

The second plot for z2 can be treated equally:

```
fun2 = I z1^2/(b1 + I b2) /. z1 -> fun1;
funs2[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] = Abs /@ fun2;
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate@funs2[a1, a2, b1, b2], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}]
 , {b1, 0.001, 1}, {b2, .001, 1}]
```

[image]